# Pythons subprocess check_call doesn't give the same result as the same command executed in the command line

Tags: python, subprocess, ogr2ogr

I am using an anaconda environment both for the python code and the terminal.

When I want to execute a program in the shell (Windows CMD) with the environment activated. The program ogr2ogr  returns the correct output with the given parameter. The tool ogr2ogr has been installed via a conda package.

But when I execute the my python code, the ogr2ogr returns an errors output. I thought it might be to different installations used due to usage of different environments (without my knowledge), but this is ownly a guess.

The python code goes as follows:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from subprocess import check_call, STDOUT
...
file_path = Path(file_name)
destination = str(file_path.with_suffix(".gpkg"))
command = f"ogr2ogr -f GPKG -s_srs EPSG:25833 -t_srs EPSG:25833 {destination} GMLAS:{file_name} -oo REMOVE_UNUSED_LAYERS=YES"

check_call(command, stderr=STDOUT, shell=True)
```

ogr2ogr translates a file into another format. Which is also done, but when I open the file, I see, it's not done 100 % correctly.
When I copy the value of the string **command** and copy it to the shell and execute the command the execution is done correctly!

How can I correct the behaviour of using subprocess.check_call

Comment: Try using the full path to the ogr2ogr executable for both Python and the shell. That should definitely eliminate the possibility that different versions of ogr2ogr might be used.

Comment: Thanks @mhawke That's that solves problem, in a way. But when using a different user or using a different computer that path has to be changed. Can It be set automatically? The program is in the \Library\bin-Subfolder of the conda environment.

Comment: I set the path of ogr2ogr to:`Path(sys.executable).parent / "Library/bin/ogr2ogr"`

Comment: My suggestion was intended to help analyse the problem by making sure that the same version of the executable is being used in both cases. I'm not sure what the best way to achieve that is in different setups, especially for Windows. Maybe you could create a new question to attract those with broader Windows knowledge.

Comment: I have a similar problem (a gpkg conversion with ogr2ogr works if I call it manually but fail with `subprocess.run` because of `no such table` error caused by a failing transaction).